# Rsyslog - forward via HTTP post

Tags: rsyslog

I am trying to setup log forwarding to log management service.
Service is accepting log messages via HTTP calls.

Using debian 8 and rsyslog 8.4.2

URL of the endpoint is http://relay.errlog.io/api/v1/log

I have added the following to `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
template(name="json-template"
  type="list") {
    constant(value="{")
      constant(value="\"errordate\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
      constant(value="\",\"apikey\":\"my-api-key")
      constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg" format="json")      
    constant(value="\"}\n")
}
action(type="omfwd" Target="relay.errlog.io/api/v1/log" Port="80" )
```

But I am not getting any messages.
What might be wrong with my configuration?
How can I troubleshoot what is being sent?

Comment: share some logs, it's impossible to solve otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

`omfwd` is syslog protocol, not http: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfwd.html